# React Native equivalent of adapting to size classes?

Tags: ios, react-native

When developing for iOS in Swift, I can configure properties and constraints to only apply to certain size classes. For example, I can modify a view's width to be 200 if horizontally constrained, or 400 if horizontally regular. Or I can [adapt a stack view to be either horizontal or vertical based on the size class](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/adapting-stack-views-with-size-classes/).

I checked the documentation and SO, and can't find similar capability in React Native. Does it exist? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

That capability is not part of React Native because React Native uses Yoga, a layout engine that is completely different from the iOS auto layout engine based on constraints.
What you can do with React Native is managing sizes and margins using percentages based on the width or the height of the screen.
This is similar to what we do to develop responsive web pages.

If you wish to go deeper about this topic I can suggest you this [article](https://medium.com/react-native-training/scaling-react-native-apps-for-tablets-211de8399cf1)

Comment: So there is no way to achieve something similar using yoga?

Comment: Not that I know of.
But I believe that in some way you could achieve what you want by developing a custom component.